# Add a dictionary created with inputs in a JSON list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, addition

I have this code reduced, the complete one has more data about the players, the purpose of this code is to add a player to enter the data requested by the program and to record that same data in a JSON file.

```
import json

class Player:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        

class FootballPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, goals):
        super().__init__(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        self.goals = goals

print("Enter some football player's data!")

f_name = input("Enter player's first name: ")
l_name = input("Enter player's last name: ")
goals = input("Enter the number of player's goals: ")

new_player = FootballPlayer(first_name=f_name, last_name=l_name, goals=int(goals))

with open("football_players.json", "r") as player_list:
    football_players =json.loads(player_list.read())
    print(str(football_players))

with open("football_players.json", "a" ) as player_list:
    player_list.write(json.dump(new_player.__dict__, player_list))
```

The problem is when i add the new player the dictionary goes out of the list created in the JSON file.

Like this:

```
[

{
"first_name": "Luis",
"last_name": "Figo",
"goals": 398}

]

{"first_name": "Daniel", "last_name": "Mord", "goals": 33}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly correct: you appended the new JSON record to the existing file.  You did *not* add it to the list.

A file knows nothing about JSON structure or Python data types.  If you want to add players to the text version of your JSON list, then you have to read in the list, append the players to the list, and write the entire list back to the file.

Alternately, you can `seek` to the end of the file, back up a line, and then (a) write all the players to the file -- which overwrites the closing bracket, and (b) write a new closing bracket.

Unless you have a huge file and notable time constraints, I suggest that you read the file with the `json` package, add your players to the Python list, and then write the entire list back to the file.